# Cómo referenciar distintos agregados en DDD

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases, ddd

Estoy empezando un proyecto en el cual estoy tratando de implementar DDD y me surgen una serie de dudas con respecto a cómo implementar la asociación entre 2 agregados que se encuentran en diferentes módulos dentro del mismo bounded context. En primer lugar tengo el siguiente agregado:

`package app.estudiosBC.oferta.grupos.domain.model;`

```
public class Grupo {
    private idGrupo idGrupo;
    private String nombre;
    //Constructor, Getters y setter obviados 
}
```

`package app.estudiosBC.oferta.cursos.domain.model;`

```
public class Curso {
    private idCurso idCurso;
    private List<Grupos> grupos; 
    //Constructor, Getters y setter obviados 
}
```

`package app.estudiosBC.calendarios.calendario.domain.model;`

`import app.estudiosBC.oferta.grupos.domain.model.idGrupo;`

```
public class Calendario {
    private idCalendario idCalendario;
    private idGrupo idGrupo;
    private Integer year;
    //Constructor, Getters y setter obviados 

}
```

Mi duda es si es correcta la importación del VO idGrupo de Calendario que se refiere al idGrupo de la entidad interna (Grupo) del otro agregado o debería crear otro VO (p.ej.:idGrupoCalendario) en Calendario y así no tener que hacer el import y depender del otro package.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones. ya que todo depende de como tengas la estructura de carpetas. por ejemplo en lo personal los agregados siempre los pongo dentro de una carpeta `shared`(compartido). Como DDD no te da una regla exacta, mas bien es una sugerencia. Tu debes de ver la mejor forma de adaptación de DDD.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.